# Httppost not firing in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http, controller

I have two buttons on a page and I want the user to click one and they both go to different pages, the problem is my httpPost attribute is not firing.

**Here is my controller:**

```
      public ActionResult Index()
    {
        if (Session["AccountConfirmationViewModel"] != null)
        {
            AccountConfirmationViewModel accountConfirmationViewModel = Session["AccountConfirmationViewModel"] as AccountConfirmationViewModel;

            if (accountConfirmationViewModel == null || !TryValidateModel(accountConfirmationViewModel))
            {
                return RedirectToAction("AccountSearch", "Home");
            }

            MobileStep1ViewModel mobileModel = new MobileStep1ViewModel();
            mobileModel.GetMobileNumbers(accountConfirmationViewModel.CustomerReferenceNumber);



            Session["MobileModel"] = mobileModel;
        }

        return View();
 }


   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(string button)
    {
        if (button == "btnNotMobileQuery")
        {
            RedirectToAction("AcconutSearch", "Home");
        }
        else if (button == "btnMobileQuery")
        {
            RedirectToAction("SecurityQuestion", "Mobile");
        }

        return View();


    }
```

**Here is my view:**

```
    @model OutsourcedTicketPlatform.UI.ViewModels.Mobile.MobileStep1ViewModel
         @using OutsourcedTicketPlatform.UI.ViewModels.Mobile        

         @{
       MobileStep1ViewModel mobileModel = Session["MobileModel"] as MobileStep1ViewModel;
    ViewBag.Title = "Mobile Issue";
}



          <h2>Mobile Issue Reporter</h2>

           <p>Hi @mobileModel.CustomerName are you phoning today to log the mobile device as lost or stolen?</p>

           @Html.RadioButton("IsMobileQuery", "MobileQuery")Yes
           @Html.RadioButton("IsMobileQuery", "NotMobileQuery")No


           <br /><br />

           <div id="NotMobileQuery" class="HideDiv">
           <input type="submit" class="btn" id="btnNotMobileQuery" value="Proceed" />
           </div>

           <div id="ConfirmMobile" class="HideDiv">
           <p>"Please Confirm your mobile number"</p>

         @foreach (var items in mobileModel.MobileNumbers)
         {
              @Html.RadioButton("SelectedMobileNumber", items)@items
         }
      <br /><br />


            <input type="submit" class="btn" id="btnMobileQuery" value="Next"  />

         </div>


         <script src="../../Scripts/Controllers/Mobile/MobileStepOne.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>

          <script src="../../Scripts/ViewModels/Mobile/MobileStepOneViewModel.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Can anyone see if I am doing anything wrong? Do I need parameter in my second index method?

Comment: Where is your <Form> ?? I dont see any form tag which should wrap your submit buttons first of all. secondly there is no any element with the name **button** which the form can post and your action method can get value from it. Refactoring is needed for your view

Comment: DO I need to wrap this around a html.BeginForm?

Comment: Yeah that is the first change you have to do. Remember the form should have "POST" method as per your Controller Action Method. After that you have to change your controller method too, and change the parameter name from button to **IsMobileQuery** because your radio button selection is needed to be passed to server. I don't see any need to have two separate submit buttons you can use only one and your server side logic can rely on the Radio button selection.

Comment: Did  you got this working friend?

Comment: Hi K D, Yes I did  thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
@model OutsourcedTicketPlatform.UI.ViewModels.Mobile.MobileStep1ViewModel
         @using OutsourcedTicketPlatform.UI.ViewModels.Mobile        

         @{
       MobileStep1ViewModel mobileModel = Session["MobileModel"] as MobileStep1ViewModel;
    ViewBag.Title = "Mobile Issue";
}

@using(Html.BeginForm("Index","Your_controller_name",FormMethod.Post)){

          <h2>Mobile Issue Reporter</h2>

           <p>Hi @mobileModel.CustomerName are you phoning today to log the mobile device as lost or stolen?</p>

           @Html.RadioButton("IsMobileQuery", "MobileQuery")Yes
           @Html.RadioButton("IsMobileQuery", "NotMobileQuery")No


           <br /><br />

           <div id="NotMobileQuery" class="HideDiv">
           <input type="submit" class="btn" id="btnNotMobileQuery" value="Proceed" />
           </div>

           <div id="ConfirmMobile" class="HideDiv">
           <p>"Please Confirm your mobile number"</p>

         @foreach (var items in mobileModel.MobileNumbers)
         {
              @Html.RadioButton("SelectedMobileNumber", items)@items
         }
      <br /><br />


            <input type="submit" class="btn" id="btnMobileQuery" value="Next"  />

         </div>
    }

         <script src="../../Scripts/Controllers/Mobile/MobileStepOne.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>

          <script src="../../Scripts/ViewModels/Mobile/MobileStepOneViewModel.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

You can use FormCollection instead of string for getting all values form view.